# Is grouping functions that form a toolbox for a specific task as classes a good idea?

Tags: c++, oop

I'm developing a big scientific computation program in C++ and I have many functions that perform some mathematical magic on the data set I import to the system. I've implemented all these functions inside a class, say Mathematics_core, but my gut says that coding classes that big is not a good idea.

However to make code readable and maintainable I'm also implementing centralized logging and will implement other all-encompassing infrastructure as needed.

Is it a good idea to encapsulate a toolbox as a class or is it better to keep them different, small functions.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they all work on the same set of private state (e.g. the first parameter of every function is `data&`) then a class may be appropriate.

Otherwise, keep them free functions. Use a namespace to group them together.

Comment: Yes, they work on the same data, same variable generally. What about the logging facilities and other things? Shall I just pass them &logger and be done with it?

Comment: @SilentStorm If you want the logger to be tied to the data then a class seems correct. Otherwise pass `logger&` as an argument or use a free instance.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are using classes as namespaces. Unless you need a class for a specific reason, use namespaces:

```
// Define like this:

namespace foo
{
    void fun(int a, int b);
}

// Use like this:

foo::fun(4, 5);
```